# SQL SELECT using multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm pretty new to using MySQL and I'm still learning.

Say I have 3 Tables in a Database `School`.
The Tables are as follows;

`Course` Contains ID(PK) and Name

`Student` Contains ID(PK), Name, etc

`Enrolment` Contains rol_num(PK), student_id and course_id.
student_id references student(id) 
course_id references course(id)

Basically Students details in the Students table, Courses details in the Courses Table, Enrolment table is a link table of students and their courses

Using a Select query command how can I get the following fields for all students courses.

student.id, student.name, course.name

Showing all Courses each student in on along with their name and id.

Comment: p.s. I'm British who speaks the one  true form of English. It's Enrolment. :P

Comment: We just kept the spelling the same as the original spelling from the languages English words come from. Americans changed it to be easier to spell as it's more like how it sounds.
Anyway, This conversations detracting from the usefulness of the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to JOIN the tables as

```
select
s.id,
s.name as student_name,
c.name as course_name
from Enrolment e
join student s on s.id = e.Student_id
join  Course c on c.id = e.course_id
```